# How does the matrix class work?

Tags: android, matrix

I have been working on a card game for android lately. Everything runs smoothly and without error, so I would like to begin touching it up a little. One thing I would like to do is to have my cards slide in from the edge of the screen when they are dealt. I heard that the matrix array class could be of great use when doing scrolling animation, but I have no clue how to do this, and online searches seem to turn up nothing of use. Is there a more practical and efficient way to do this than by using the matrix? If not, could somebody explain how the matrix works?

Comment: it looks you did not search hard enough, how about this? it has video demo too !!!! http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/10/create-animation-using-matrix.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and attach an [Animator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html) to the card objects. (or just load the animation and play it when needed, which I'll show below using some code)

Then you'll need to create a folder in res called anim, in that folder create two files:

slide_up_left.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/config_slide_time"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="@integer/config_slide_time"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

    <rotate
        android:duration="@integer/config_slide_time"
        android:fromDegrees="25"
        android:pivotX="0"
        android:pivotY="0"
        android:toDegrees="0" />

</set>
```

slide_up_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/config_slide_time"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="@integer/config_slide_time"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

    <rotate
        android:duration="@integer/config_slide_time"
        android:fromDegrees="-25"
        android:pivotX="100%"
        android:pivotY="0"
        android:toDegrees="0" />

</set>
```

And create a xml file called integers in your values folder that contains this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <integer name="config_slide_time">800</integer>
</resources>
```

If you don't need an Animator object use this code:

```
YOURCARD_VIEW.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_up_left));
```

Or

```
YOURCARD_VIEW.startAnimation( AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_up_right));
```

The YOURCARD_VIEW is a View object so you must have the card defined as a View

Comment: Thank you, lad. This is a great deal easier than using the matrix

Comment: No problem at all, after I posted this question I realized that it has nothing to do with the matrix :-P

Comment: I just realized: my cards are drawn into the canvas, so the only way I can get motion is by moving the entire canvas, and that's going to create too many problems. Is there any way I can use this same method with drawables?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html. How is the canvas drawed? Using an ImageView? You can apply the animation to the ImageView aswell

Comment: Anytime!! The animations are working on every class that extends the class View. If you take a look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html you'll see that beneath the big TextView line it says extends View, that's how you recognize if something has been extended by the View class